# Make a Scheduled job for Renaming the files in a folder and send an updated alert email

Tags: shell-script, email, rename

I am writing a shell script, which can rename all the files in the folder,

We need to search for a particular pattern of files every 30 seconds.

Files in the below format need to be selected,

```
    core.3467
    core.1234
    core.acde
```

and they need to be updated as below,

```
    c.o.r.e.3467
    c.o.r.e.1234
    c.o.r.e.acde
```

once they are updated an alert email has to be sent that file core.3467 has been changed to c.o.r.e.3467

This is what i have written until now, rename command doesn't seem to work though,

```
#!/bin/bash
#go the designated directory
cd "<dir_name>"
mail="abc@xyz.com"
#writing all the files in the specified format
ls core* > current.txt
a='cat current.txt'

#renaming the file
rename "s/core/c.o.r.e."*

#writing updated file names
ls c.o.r.e* > updated.txt
b='cat updated.txt'

#sending alert email
mail -s "Files $a changed to $b" $mail
```

Comment: Be careful, there's two incompatible tools by the name of `rename`. (Also, I don't think `a` and `b` will contain what you think, you need `$(cat ...)` I think?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

email_address=me@my.domain.com

for file in $(ls /my/directory/name/core*)
do
  newname=$(echo ${file}|sed -e "1,1s/core/c.o.r.e/")
  mv ${file} ${newname}
  echo "File Renamed..."|mail -s "File ${file} renamed to ${newname} ${email_address}
done
```

This should do...

Comment: This workes fine. But in case i need single email for all the files renamed at a point, how should i change this script?

Comment: In case if there are no files i am getting an error "No such file or directory" >> how to handle this error???

Answer (score 0):

Giving all due credit to MelBuslan's excellent scriptlet, let me tweak it to address the request for one single e-mail:

```
#!/bin/bash

email_address=me@my.domain.com

if test -n "$(find /my/directory/name -maxdepth 1 -name 'core*' -print -quit)" ; then
    for file in $(ls /my/directory/name/core*)
    do
      newname=$(echo ${file}|sed -e "1,1s/core/c.o.r.e/")
      mv ${file} ${newname}
      echo "File ${file} renamed to ${newname}" >> updated.txt
    done
    cat updated.txt | mail -s "Files renamed" ${email_address}
    rm updated.txt
fi
```

Comment: Updated to also include dealing with the case where there's a non-existent file

Comment: @micheal : it is giving me an error in line 5: saying too many arguments. I tried to put the path in quotes which cleared the error but it just doesnt work. The files are not getting updated.

Comment: **UPDATE** That is correct; I've updated my code to remove the "too many arguments flaw" using a different if clause.  It should work now.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script